# What does 本当のところ means in this context?

Tags: meaning, translation, syntax, sentence

> もっとも内面的には、今とさほど変わらない、未熟な精神的幼稚園児と言うしかない気もする。当時と今で、僕の人間性に大きな違いがあるとも思えない。だが、これはあくまで本人がそう思っているだけであって、過去を美化していたり、現在を卑下していたり、あるいはその逆だったり、そんなこんなで辻棲を合わせているだけで本当のところは色々あるのだろう。

So , here the writer speaks about his past self and how he feels that it is not so different compared to his current self  or so he love to think saying that his attempted to beautify the past and abase the present or vise versa what I don't understand is his nest sentence speaking about how attempting to make ends meet makes makes truth abundant?

Comment: Is the passage extracted from a novel? When I google some of the phrases, the name 西尾維新 shows up.

Comment: Yes,indeed it is .

Comment: Is,  he saying that in an attempt to make things logical there is places where you ether beautify or abase the past and the present?

Answer (score 1):

「本当のところ」can be replaced 「実際には」「実際のところ」in this context.

Comment: So what does he basically mean by そんなこんなで辻棲を合わせているだけで本当のところは色々あるのだろう ?

Comment: @user50156, hiroki has answered your main question (the one you put in the title of your post), so I think maybe you should upvote and accept this answer, then ask a new question if you still don't understand the passage. But here's something that might help: It looks like there's a typo either in the original text or in your quotation of it, as it should say 辻褄 (つじつま) rather than 辻棲. If you look up this word, and the phrase 辻褄が合う, that might help you understand the meaning of the clause you're asking about. Also note that 色々あるのだろう refers not to "truth" (本当), but to "big differences" (大きな違い).